# Check if a file contains a certain pattern?

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

ps

ps -ef > test.txt
```

Now if I want to check whether test.txt has certain keywords present, in it, how do we go about?

Let's say 'apache' or 'fast'.

Can we use the if statement here, if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all the first shebang line is not what you want for your script. expect as a shell has a limited use and this is not one of them

first line should be something like

```
#!/bin/bash
```

in your case

then

```
ps -ef > test.txt
grep -e fast -e apache test.txt
```

will print you all the lines containing either of these words.

or you can skip the writing to file step and do it in one line as such:

```
ps -ef | grep -e fast -e apache
```

EDIT for conditional check:

```
ps -ef | grep -e fast -e apache | grep -v grep > dev/null; result=${?}
if [ ${result} -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "Found one or more occurrences of 'apache' and/or 'fast'"
else
  echo "Searched strings were not found"
fi
```

Comment: I think you want to drop `test.txt` from your last option, also, your command will also find itself which is probably not what's desired, probably `pgrep` could be used though I'm not sure I've used it to match either usernames or commands (e.g., the apache user and the apache process) if that is indeed the intent of the OP

Comment: victim of quick copy and paste :) corrected & thanks

Comment: Thanks. Can we use a conditional statement to check whether a string is present and print/echo yes/no?

Comment: Please see my EDIT

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an array in here

```
#!/bin/bash

string=('fast' 'apache')

ps -ef > test.txt

for i in "$string[@]"
do
    grep "$i" test.txt
done
```

Or you can do it directly in the `ps` line to save only those processes

```
#!/bin/bash

string=('fast' 'apache')

for i in "$string[@]"
do
    ps -ef | grep "$i" > ps_output_of_$i.txt
done
```

Give a try

Comment: Thanks. Can we use grep to check whether the string exists in the text file and echo yes/no?